# What's the opposite of nominal in the astronaut sense?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

If some sub-system is not nominal, what do they say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If something is nominal, then it is acting as expected, i.e., all measurements of the system are coming back in the normal/acceptable range.  It's shorthand for all measurements of system X are operating as expected.

If something is not nominal, it does no good to say "not nominal", rather, one would say what is actually wrong.  For instance, if fuel tank pressure was below its safe/acceptable value, they would report that the fuel tank pressure is low.  That's why there appear to be a million dials or so in cockpits in addition to a computer interface.  When something is off, exactly what is off is reported, and that is what the pilot / astronaut will relay.

Comment: Mark has a fantastic insight - he is so right.  If you're low on fuel, you'd scream **Low on fuel!** or just **Emergency!**  If everything is just ticking along OK, they just keep mumbling "nominal."

Answer (score 11):

I don’t know what they actually *say* (did a bit of Googling for Apollo records, but couldn't find what I wanted there). As “nominal” means “that has its nominal (aka normal) value”, the common word that comes to mind is ***abnormal***.

*In writing*, however, it is perfectly fine to refer to such a situation as ***off-nominal***. This term is found in plenty of technical reports and manuals of aircraft. See also, for example, this NASA webpage: [*Emergency, Abnormal, and Off-nominal Situations Study*](https://web.archive.org/web/20111024222841/http://human-factors.arc.nasa.gov/eas/).

Answer (score 0):

I remember it being described as an anomaly being used to discuss deviations from the normal condition. I don't remember that in any radio calls. However in discussion, interview, and press release situations, it was used in reference to situations or results that were not normal or expected. One Wiki definition in under software anomaly is anything that differs from expectations, whether the expectations resulted from documentation, experiences, or otherwise. I think that works well for most other things.

Answer (score 0):

@david-moles answer is really excellent and has a good cited reference. I present this just as a supplement to his answer:

[Aeronautics and Space Report of the President FY1999](https://history.nasa.gov/presrep99/pages/glossary.html) gives an "official definition":

> Nominal:  Functioning as designed

So perhaps it would help us to use a trial substitution to see which of the three terms (emergency, abnormal, or off-nominal) fit better:

"All systems nominal" does seem to be a good choice when "all systems functioning as designed" is what you want to convey.
yet 
"off-nominal situation up here!" would correspond to "not as-designed situation up here!" which is probably not as clear as "abnormal situation up here!" since we generally don't "design" situations in the same sense that we "design" systems.

And yet, to play my own devil's advocate, here is an interesting quote from the [NASA Systems Engineering Handbook](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/nasa_systems_engineering_handbook_0.pdf)

> "The ConOps should include scenarios for all significant operational situations, including known **off-nominal situations**."

Moreover, the word "abnormal" did not appear in that handbook (according to a quick word search operation)! There are several more interesting varying usages of "off-nominal" in the handbook as well.

As an aside, @John, the original poster did *not* specify context as limited to America or NASA and there are other countries with space programs which may have their own lexicon that differs. Although, at present, NASA is surely the leader in this field in the English speaking world.

In summary, David's answer of "off-nominal" seems to be the most correct answer, particularly from a NASA perspective, but "abnormal" is recognized to some extent by NASA as well, and would probably be better recognized by a more general audience.

Answer (score 0):

"Anominal" ought to be acceptable, though I couldn't find it as such in a dictionary.  It should be easily understood, considering people do know "anomaly". I would still go with "abnormal" if at all possible.

Comment: For [tag:single-word-requests], if it's not in a dictionary then it doesn't realy work as an answer. (Hint: You could [edit] with "anomalous" and provide a suitable link though.) Please talke the [tour] and when you have free-time, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Welcome to EL&U.